# Artificially limit memory available for celery worker

Tags: python, django, out-of-memory, celery

I have a (what I think fairly standard) setup with a Django server + redis + celery.

Depending on the task being delegated to the celery worker, sometimes I get:

```
[2020-07-21 19:58:17,401: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:31695 exited with 'signal 9 (SIGKILL)'
[2020-07-21 19:58:17,469: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1267, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 9 (SIGKILL).
```

From what I can tell, the worker is being killed because the system ran out of memory.

I would like to be able to simulate that problem in a testing environment. How can I artificially limit the memory available to a celery worker (or all workers) or simulate a worker exiting this way?

Comment: Is [this docs entry](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/workers.html#max-memory-per-child-setting) helpful at all?

Comment: I saw this, but could not really find what I was looking for (without having something much more sophisticated in my test setup to kill a worker after it has been launched, before it has completed...etc...)

Comment: why wouldn't  you just raise same error in test, what are you trying to achieve in test setup

Comment: You could just limit the memory while starting your worker: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: @iklinac ... yes, that sounds good... how?